# How do we do Graph representation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, heuristics

The real question is how to represent a graph data structure in ruby (some example code might help me understand).

I currently have an idea to represent a graph. that is every `Node` has an `array` of `neighbourNodes` which are `object_id` of node objects. Is there any better solution? Can i achieve this with some library easily. I have looked at `GRATR` and `RGL`. both are outdated (atleast i think so.) Anyway any working example on tuby 2.0.0 will help me a lot.

I have `Busstops` which compose `Routes`. `Routes`is a sequence of `Busstops`. How would I represent the graph for all the `Routes`. I want to use Dijkstra's Algorith to find a shortest path between two busstops (which may or may not lie on the same `Route`. Which means you have to change a bus on the way)).

Comment: You can use a graph database such as Neo4j which is designed to work with graphs

Comment: @SamD yes i have considered that. but i have already a postgres database. and more importantly i need to run Dijkstra's algo or A* algorithm on it. so it needs to be in memory. with neo4j there will be thousands of queries to the database which is a real performance hit.What you say?

Comment: It depends I still think Neo4j would be a better choice for you now as it has Dijkstra's algo already built in and does indexing on nodes. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-graph-algos.html

Comment: and moreover if a database with indexes(in memory) won't be able to handle your data set then ruby definitely cannot.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it. Im out of time on this project. And i would really not want to get involved in learning neo4j( only due to time shortage). (i would love to but there are time restraints. So is there any quick way to solve this problem besides this?

Comment: the only way i can think of right now is using POSTGIS if you have latitude and longitude for busstops. POSTGIS is relatively easy to pick up because it uses SQL and is an extension of Postgres

Comment: you can also add pgRouting

Comment: @SamD can you please put this in answer so that i can award the bounty.

Comment: just posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, since you do not want to use a new data store such as Neo4j, the best option is using [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.net/) and [pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/). They are relatively easy to implement as they use SQL and are extensions for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5):

This question is really vague, so you should expect to receive vague answers. Here's mine:

---

**It's All Data**

When you're looking to do something visually, it all starts with data

Your `busstops` have `routes` -- this means nothing to Rails or your graphing system. What will mean something is numbers &  data; specifically geolocational data (for the bus stops & other geolocational data)

We've never done anything with maps or routes; so I don't know how you'd plot a route, and find the nearest bus stop. I do know, however, that in order to get that working, you'll definitely need to pull the correct data from your database

---

**How I'd Approach It**

I'd start by getting all the data you'll need stored in the database:

- Each bus stop needs a location (long & lat value)
- Each bus stop's route needs to be mapped out (perhaps with sequential [waypoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waypoint) of locational data)
- You need a "reference" point (long & lat value to gauge against)

Once you have all these values in place, you'll then be able to get some sort of process sorted to show the data on the graph

Comment: Yes i've latlong for the busstops. I dont need the sequential waypoints.

Comment: How do you do the routes then?

Comment: i was hoping you will explain the graph construction. or how we do graph representation in ruby language.

Comment: A `Route` is a sequence of busstops

Comment: Okay - Graphs would be done in Javascript -- you'd pass the data to the graph with something like [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon). Hope this helps?

Comment: im writing an api for an iPhone app. so no javascript. all has to be done in server (RoR)

Comment: lol of course! What I meant was on the front-end, you'll _have_ to use javascript (to display the graph). The JS front-end just uses a series of arrays to populate the graph, which you can get from your ROR app

Comment: I dont think you understand. I have to run dijkstra's algorithm on the graph on the server. Which will construct a route (series of bus stops).which will be sent to the device which will display the route with apple maps. Now i only need to know how we represent a graph (data structure) in ruby.I have looked at few graphing frameworks like GRATR and rgl. but i need some example code for better understanding.

Comment: Anyway its a `graph` data structure. not a visual graph with bars and lines and so.

Answer (score 0):

Since i asked a graph representation in ruby.i came up with this idea that every Node is connected to some other `Nodes` called `Edges`.
In ruby I create a `Node Object` and then push other `Node's`object_id`s to this`Node.

```
newNode.neighbours << otherNode.object_id
```

There might me other ways.  But this came to my mind. Please do tell me if there is a better way to do this.

For now this is what im using.